# Django CSS/JS MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch Error

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I'm developing a a web application which runs on a local server provided by django. The first page index.html has many CSS and javascript files. But, none of them is properly rendered on browser. All the **css/js files** show same **MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) error**.  The firefox console shows the error briefly -

The resource from “http://localhost:8000/C:/Users/PYTHON/foodie/static/plugins/scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js” was `blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your static files settings in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/static'),
]
```

and add this in master `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.... Can you please explain why we need to append the urlpatterns of urls.py? This thing needs to be done only when we are running it locally why?

Comment: Because the project is currently on your local server and web servers such as Nginx or Apache are not installed on your local server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. If possible please edit your answer by adding the 'from django.conf.urls.static import static' statement in the beginning for urls.py file.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **DEBUG** is set to **True** in your settings